# Example Code for Pickerview and Tableview together

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm searching for some example project/source code for an app with a **Pickerview** *and* a **Tableview** together as subviews. No fancy animations or anything, just the two together at the same time. I can get both working fine separately but I can't get them both together in the same project despite searching for sample code for the last couple of weeks.

Clearly I'm a neophyte but a little help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This demo might help: [DateCell UIPIcker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html)